# iMacros Loop for beginners

Tags: loops, imacros

I've worked with the language before on an ultra simple task. Since i dont want to learn iMacros, i am not into it.

It is [these pages](http://statlib.nsi.bg:8181/bg/lister.php?iid=DO-010004366) i need to save - one by one. Here was my try:

```
VERSION BUILD=11.0.246.4051
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !LOOP 434
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=* WAIT=YES
URL GOTO=http://statlib.nsi.bg:8181/bg/lister.php?iid=DO-010004366&page={{!LOOP}}
```

... but it doesn't work ... Here's what happens:

it goes directly to URL "....page=434" not having anything downloaded and lets the timer just tick ....

Comment: Do you see any error or warning?

Comment: See [this wiki page](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) .

Answer (score 0):

To visit each page, simply use the next button on the top, which would look like this:

```
SET !LOOP -434
TAB T=1
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>A" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=1
```

However to download each page, i dont know how to do that.